# Taylor formula for y=tanx at x= 0

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need to write a Taylor formula for $y=\tan x$ at the point $x=0$ till the member of second order ( does that means till second derivative or just an element on Taylor expansion?)

so my soultion: $f(0)=0 ; f'(0)=1 ; f''(0)= \frac{2\cdot \sin x}{\cos^3(x)}=0$?

then the Taylor expansion till second order member ( can somepne tell me, what's the appropriate name for it?) is $P_n(x)= 0 + x + ? $

How can I calculate the last element?

Comment: You're looking for what is called a "second-order expansion." This means the highest term in your expansion is of degree 2, i.e., an $x^2$ term.

Comment: Given you have $f'(0)=1$ , the answer is unlikely to be $0+0+0$

Comment: $f'(0)=\mathbf 1$, $\tan x \approx x$

Comment: To  Henry: ok, it's 0+ x, but how can I calculate the third member, if sin(0) is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you computed correctly $$f(0)=0,\quad  f'(0)=1,\quad f''(0)=0$$
the second order Taylor polynomial of $f:=\tan$ at $x=0$ is
$$j^2_0\tan(x)=0+1\cdot x+{1\over2}\cdot0 \cdot x^2=x\ .$$

Comment: Thank you. Most helpful of answers.

Answer (score 1):

Do synthetic division of

$\begin{array}\\
\tan(x)
&=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\\
&=\dfrac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}...}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...}\\
&=x\dfrac{1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}+...}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Yeah, and that’s the way I look at it and would do it.